# HTML apuntar a cierta parte de mi pagina web

Tags: javascript, html, html5, bootstrap

Tengo una parte en mi página web que renderiza objetos, digamos una tabla, mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que mi navegador apunte a la parte que recién se creó?

Supongamos que tengo lo siguiente y que lo que necesito es que la vista apunte a la tabla que acabo de crear. No sé si necesito un `<section>` o si basta con solo referenciar el objeto por la url, ¿cuál es la mejor forma de hacer esto?

```js
function t-render(t1){
     document.getElementById('amortiz').innerHTML += `
            <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-2">`+ t1.toFixed(2) + `</td>
            <td class="col-xs-2">`+ t1.toFixed(2) + `</td>
            <td class="col-xs-2">`+ t1.toFixed(2) + `</td>
            <td class="col-xs-2">`+ t1.toFixed(2) + `</td>` +
                `<td class="col-xs-2">` + t1.toFixed(2) + `</td>` +


                `<td class="col-xs-2">` + t1.toFixed(2) + `</td>

        </tr>`;}
```

```html
d
<div>

  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Aqui tengo navegor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    Datos que ya vienen en la página
    <input type="button" name="name" value="" onclick="renderTabla" />
    <img src="#" alt="Alternate Text" />
    <form action="/" method="post"></form>
    <!-- y otras cosas -->
  </div>

  <div id="t-render"></div>


  <div>
    Datos que ya vienen en la página
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Quieres que apenas se renderize se mueva la pantalla hasta la parte de tu tabla?

Answer (score 5):

Si entendí correctamente, lo que quieres es que el navegador realice el scroll hasta la parte que quieres. Si le añades un atributo `id` en el elemento que quieres que aparezca arriba de todo el en la pantalla con poner ese id en la url sería suficiente. Ejemplo:

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#segundo-div">ir a segundo div</a>
<div>
  Primer Div
</div>
<div id="segundo-div">
  Segundo div
</div>
```

en cualquier momento puedes llamar esa url también con js `window.location = '#segundo-div';`.

Si quieres algo más complicado, podrías usar `window.scroll(x,y)` y le pasas como argumento la posición del elemento que sacas con `element.getBoundingClientRect();`

```js
document.getElementById("accion").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const posicionY = document.getElementById("segundo-div").getBoundingClientRect().top;
  window.scroll(0, posicionY);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<button id="accion">ir a segundo div</button>
<div>
  Primer Div
</div>
<div id="segundo-div">
  Segundo div
</div>
```